# С помощью чего написать интеграционные тесты для JMS

Tags: java, junit, test-automation

Имеется сервер WebSphere на нём устанавливаются приложения ear, которые принимают и отправляют сообщения по JMS. Возник вопрос, с помощью чего написать интеграционные тесты, которые бы выполнялись перед сборкой приложения? Тесты должны имитировать прием и отправку сообщения.
Если использовать mockito, то выходит все не совсем гладко и приходится мокать все подряд и в итоге решили отказаться от этой затеии. Поделитесь опытом, кто писал такие тесты

Comment: Посмотрите инструмент JMeter здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/248453/ ,  https://habr.com/ru/post/437172/, а для самостоятельного написания тестов - здесь: https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/

Comment: @anshap угу, спасибо, знаю такой инструмент, но хотелось бы, чтобы именно в коде во время сборки выполнялись вместе с юнит тестами. Не знаю мб это и никто не делает и всегда обходятся JMeterом, но для развития кругозора хотел и этот вариант прочекать)

Comment: Если речь идёт о сервере WebSphere MQ, то на сайте IBM (https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/develop-mq-jms/) показан пример использования библиотеки com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar для отправки и получения клиентом JMS-сообщения из очереди MQ.